# Facebook: When a page clicks my 'like' buton, the count does not increase

Tags: facebook, button, like

I have a small Facebook problem.
I have created a page for my business and placed a 'like' button at the top.
When an individual clicks like the count increases but if another business page clicks like it does not update the count, even though I get notification that they have clicked.
Is there any way I can add the two counts together to show a total amount of likes?

Many thanks
Cate

Comment: What do you mean by "if another business page clicks like"? That doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

A good first step is to run your page URL through [Facebook's debugger.](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) It should report any problems with your page that might cause issues with Like buttons.